# Deal with PatternSyntaxException and scanning texts

Tags: java, regex

I want to find names in a collection of text documents from a huge list of about 1 million names. I'm making a Pattern from the names of the list first:

```
    BufferedReader TSVFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("names.tsv"));

    String dataRow = TSVFile.readLine();
    dataRow = TSVFile.readLine();// skip first line (header)

    String combined = "";
    while (dataRow != null) {
        String[] dataArray = dataRow.split("\t");
        String name = dataArray[1];
        combined += name.replace("\"", "") + "|";

        dataRow = TSVFile.readLine(); // Read next line of data.
    }
    TSVFile.close();
    Pattern all = Pattern.compile(combined);
```

After doing so I got an `IllegalPatternSyntax` Exception because some names contain a `'+'` in their names or other Regex expressions. I tried solving this by either ignoring the few names by:

```
    if(name.contains("\""){
    //ignore this name }
```

Didn't work properly but also messy because you have to escape everything manually and run it many times and waste your time.
Then I tried using the `quote` method:

```
   Pattern all = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(combined));
```

However now, I don't find any matches in the text documents anymore, even when I also use `quote` on the them. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I think the problem is in that you also quote the pipe symbol which should be escaped

Comment: Perhaps you can manually quote the names when you construct the regex like this: combined += "\\Q" + name + "\\E|";

Comment: This might not answer your question, but: regular expressions (meaning those provided by `java.util.regex`) do not scale well, especially not at searching. Better use a Multi-String-Search-Algorithm (such as Aho-Corasick).

Comment: @CoronA Do you know where I can get support for the Aho-Corasick implementation from https://github.com/robert-bor/aho-corasick ? I'm wondering how I can add keywords in a loop.

Comment: Should be quite simple: Create a `trieBuilder = new Trie.builder()` before the loop. Add `trieBuilder.addKeyword(keyword)` in the loop. Call `Trie trie = trieBuilder.build()` to get the final trie. If this does not solve your problem, then I recommend to open another question on this (and point me to it).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment of @dragon66, you should not quote pipe "|". So your code would be like the code below using `Pattern.quote()` :

```
BufferedReader TSVFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("names.tsv"));

String dataRow = TSVFile.readLine();
dataRow = TSVFile.readLine();// skip first line (header)

String combined = "";
while (dataRow != null) {
    String[] dataArray = dataRow.split("\t");
    String name = dataArray[1];
    combined += Pattern.quote(name.replace("\"", "")) + "|"; //line changed

    dataRow = TSVFile.readLine(); // Read next line of data.
}
TSVFile.close();
Pattern all = Pattern.compile(combined);
```

Also I suggest to verify if your problem domain needs optimization replacing the use of the `String combined = "";` over an Immutable `StringBuilder` class to avoid the creation of unnecessary new strings inside a loop.

Comment: Would that also be an improvement if each `String` was unique?

Comment: @Pete If each `String` is unique, then you're definitely going to eat up lots of memory with your repeated concatenations.  9/10 times, you want a `StringBuilder` for repeated concatenations, and the other 1/10 is when you need to worry about synchronization and thus use a `StringBuffer` instead.

Answer (score 0):

guilhermerama presented the bugfix to your code.

I will add some performance improvements. As I pointed out the regex library of java does not scale and is even slower if used for searching.

But one can do better with Multi-String-Seach algorithms. For example by using [StringsAndChars String Search](https://github.com/almondtools/stringsandchars#string-search):

```
//setting up a test file
Iterable<String> lines = createLines();
Files.write(Paths.get("names.tsv"), lines , CREATE, WRITE, TRUNCATE_EXISTING);

// read the pattern from the file
BufferedReader TSVFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("names.tsv"));

Set<String> combined = new LinkedHashSet<>();

String dataRow = TSVFile.readLine();
dataRow = TSVFile.readLine();// skip first line (header)

while (dataRow != null) {
  String[] dataArray = dataRow.split("\t");
  String name = dataArray[1];
  combined.add(name);

  dataRow = TSVFile.readLine(); // Read next line of data.
}

TSVFile.close();

// search the pattern in a small text
StringSearchAlgorithm stringSearch = new AhoCorasick(new ArrayList<>(combined));
StringFinder finder = stringSearch.createFinder(new StringCharProvider("test " + name(38) + "\n or " + name(799) + " : " + name(99999), 0));
System.out.println(finder.findAll());
```

The result will be

```
[5:10(00038), 15:20(00799), 23:28(99999)]
```

The search (`finder.findAll()`) does take (on my computer) < 1 millisecond. Doing the same with java.util.regex took around 20 milliseconds.

You may tune this performance by using other algorithms provided by RexLex.

Setting up needs following code:

```
private static Iterable<String> createLines() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)  {
        list.add(i + "\t" + name(i));
    }
    return list;
}

private static String name(int i) {
    String s = String.valueOf(i);
    while (s.length() < 5)  {
        s = '0' + s;
    }
    return s;
}
```